# Connect to XAMPP MySQL Database from Document Root on another Drive

Tags: php, mysql

would like to ask about configuration of XAMPP mySQL database.

I have set my xampp document root to drive D, and now i unable to connect to SQL database and always get error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in D:\localserver\connection.php:3 Stack trace: #0 D:\localserver\login.php(4): include() #1 {main} thrown in D:\localserver\connection.php on line 3
```

the file that handle the connection look like this

```
<?php 
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  if(!$connect) {
    die ('connection fail!!!');
  } else {
    print ('connection okay!!!');
  }
$connectdb = mysql_select_db('admin_login');
  if(!$connectdb) {
    die ('connection fail!!!');
  } else {
    print ('connection okay!!!');
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysql_connect()` function is from a library that is deprecated since a couple of years and has been removed in PHP 7.

Use `mysqli_connect()` or PDO.

**UPDATE**

You can pass the name of the database into `mysqli_connect()` and get rid of the extra `mysqli_select_db()`. If you want to user `mysqli_select_db()` in procedural style instead of object oriented it expects the link that is returned by `mysqli_connect()` as the first parameter and the database name as the second one like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $password);
$db = mysqli_select_db($link, $dbname);
```

Comment: thank for fast answer, i try to change it to mysqli_connect(), and the connection is okay, but still got this error, mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\localserver\connection.php on line 9